# What may be wrong with String::ToIdentifier::EN tests?

Tags: perl

I try to install Perl module `String::ToIdentifier::EN` (as depndency of `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`) but it fails on tests. I googled those errors but get no picture, where is problem:

```
Building and testing String-ToIdentifier-EN-0.07
cp lib/String/ToIdentifier/EN.pm blib/lib/String/ToIdentifier/EN.pm
cp lib/String/ToIdentifier/EN/Unicode.pm blib/lib/String/ToIdentifier/EN/Unicode.pm
Manifying blib/man3/String::ToIdentifier::EN.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/String::ToIdentifier::EN::Unicode.3pm
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/00_basic.t t/10_ascii.t t/20_capitalization.t
Byte order is not compatible at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/Storable/_retrieve.al) line 380, at /home/wanradt/perl5/lib/perl5/Lingua/EN/Tagger.pm line 167
# Looks like you planned 25 tests but ran 4.
# Looks like your test exited with 25 just after 4.
t/00_basic.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 25 (wstat 6400, 0x1900)
Failed 21/25 subtests 
Byte order is not compatible at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/Storable/_retrieve.al) line 380, at /home/wanradt/perl5/lib/perl5/Lingua/EN/Tagger.pm line 167
# Looks like you planned 768 tests but ran 512.
# Looks like your test exited with 25 just after 512.
t/10_ascii.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 25 (wstat 6400, 0x1900)
Failed 256/768 subtests 
t/20_capitalization.t .. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/00_basic.t         (Wstat: 6400 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
Non-zero exit status: 25
Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 25 tests but ran 4.
t/10_ascii.t         (Wstat: 6400 Tests: 512 Failed: 0)
Non-zero exit status: 25
Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 768 tests but ran 512.
Files=3, Tests=528,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.02 sys +  0.42 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.55 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/3 test programs. 0/528 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing String::ToIdentifier::EN failed. See /home/wanradt/.cpanm/build.log for details.
```

`Byte order is not compatible at...` seems a key, but to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what went wrong, but solution was to remove local (in user-base) bundle of Perl modules and install them again.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar errors (not with `String::ToIdentifier::EN`, though) in 64-bit systems where an enterprise-grade-commercial-application-I'm-not-gonna-name-here overwrote the RHEL provided 64-bit Perl installation with a 32-bit version of Perl.

That caused all kind of funny side-effects when trying to fetch something from CPAN... I was not very amused. So, if you have a 64-bit OS, try `file /usr/bin/perl` and see what it returns.

Comment: Thank you, but my system is 32bit Ubuntu.